# How should I tidy up this code:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsnull

```
if ([dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"LikeNumber"] isNotEmpty]) {
    BusinessToSave.numberOfLike =dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"LikeNumber"];
}
else
{
    BusinessToSave.numberOfLike = @(0);
}

if (dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"DislikeNumber"])
{
    BusinessToSave.numberOfDislike =dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"DislikeNumber"];
}
else
{
    BusinessToSave.numberOfDislike =@(0);
}

//BusinessToSave.buildingName =dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"];

if([dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"] isNotEmpty]){
    BusinessToSave.buildingName=dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"];
}
else
{
    BusinessToSave.buildingName =nil;
}


if([dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Street"] isNotEmpty]){
    BusinessToSave.Street=dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Street"];
}
else
{
    BusinessToSave.Street =nil;
}
```

Obviously this is quite messy for one simple reason.

`BusinessToSave` is a managedObject.

Often it should simply go to nil. However, dictionary cannot contain nil value and would return NULL instead.

So I can't just do `BusinessToSave.buildingName = dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"]`

What should I do then?

One thing I tried is:

```
BusinessToSave.buildingName =(NSString*) [dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"] nilIfNull];
```

Another thing I tried is

```
BusinessToSave.buildingName =((NSString*) dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"]).nilIfNull;
```

I have no idea why the dot notation could work given that nilIfNull returns id

```
-(id) nilIfNull
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        return self;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I finally settle for

`[dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"] nilIfNull]` which works if I expect NSString. Are there better or more standard way?

Comment: what is "`@(0);`" doing?  I've never seen Objective C that looks like that.  How is your "`dictInfoForThisBusiness`" method declared?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: [Objective-C object literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann It's `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`.

Answer (score 3):

A first step would be to try and rid yourself of all those else statements. Simply changing this setup(?) method to something like this would make it more readable:

```
BusinessToSave.numberOfLike = @(0);
if ([dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"LikeNumber"] isNotEmpty]) {
    BusinessToSave.numberOfLike =dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"LikeNumber"];
}

BusinessToSave.numberOfDislike =@(0);
if (dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"DislikeNumber"]){
    BusinessToSave.numberOfDislike =dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"DislikeNumber"];
}

BusinessToSave.buildingName =nil;
if([dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"] isNotEmpty]){
    BusinessToSave.buildingName=dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Building"];
}

BusinessToSave.Street =nil;
if([dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Street"] isNotEmpty]){
    BusinessToSave.Street=dictInfoForThisBusiness[@"Street"];
}
```

How about creating a method to give you the correct object (or nil):

```
BusinessToSave.buildingName = [self valueForDictKey:@"Building"];
```

You could even have two (or more) different methods. (stringForDictKey, integerForDictKey) etc.

```
BusinessToSave.numberOfLike = [self integerForDictKey:@"LikeNumber"];
BusinessToSave.numberOfDislike = [self integerForDictKey: @"DislikeNumber"];
BusinessToSave.buildingName = [self stringForDictKey: @"Building"];
BusinessToSave.street = [self stringForDictKey @"Street"];
```

Also: I'd advice you to make some #defines for all those keys, it is way too easy to misspell one of those key-names. :)

```
BusinessToSave.numberOfLike = [self integerForDictKey:KEY_LIKES];
BusinessToSave.numberOfDislike = [self integerForDictKey: KEY_DISLIKES];
BusinessToSave.buildingName = [self stringForDictKey: KEY_BUILDING];
BusinessToSave.street = [self stringForDictKey KEY_STREET];
```

Comment: the whole point of the issue is that BusinessToSave.buildingName should be nil rather than NULL.

Comment: It might be me being thick as a brick. But wouldn't a string-property treat nil, NULL and 0 exactly the same?

Comment: nil and 0 should be the same. not sure about NULL though.